# not hiding the textarea when uncheck the checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox

i have the code given below:
its working fine when i click on the rejected checkbox it shows the textarea but its not hiding it when i uncheck the rejected checkbox.

Please help....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkValue() {
    var rejected=document.forms["frmcnt"]["ar"].checked

    if (rejected = 'Rejected') {
        document.getElementById('xtraInfo').style.display='';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('xtraInfo').style.display='none';
    }   
}   
</script>

Accepted: <input type='checkbox' name='ar' value='Accepted' />
Rejected: <input type='checkbox' name='ar' value='Rejected' onClick="return checkValue(this)" />

  <div id="xtraInfo" style="text-align:center; display:none; font-weight:bold;">
    <center>Rejection Detail:</center><br>
    <textarea width="900" style="width: 910px; resize:vertical;" name="rejectdt"><?php if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' ) { print_r($_POST['rejectdt']); } ?></textarea>
  </div>
```

Comment: You're not using jQuery here, what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:

```
 Rejected: <input type='checkbox' name='reject' id='reject' value='Rejected' onClick="checkValue()" />
```

function :

```
function checkValue() 
{

if(document.getElementById("reject").checked == true)
 {
   document.getElementById('xtraInfo').style.display='block';
 }
else
 {
   document.getElementById('xtraInfo').style.display='none';
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`document.forms["frmcnt"]["ar"].checked` returns `true` or `false`, change to:

```
if (rejected) {
    document.getElementById('xtraInfo').style.display='block';
} else {
    document.getElementById('xtraInfo').style.display='none';
}
```

Update:: since you are doing `onClick="return checkValue(this)"`, do

```
function checkValue(obj) {
    var rejected=obj.checked;

    if (rejected) {
       document.getElementById('xtraInfo').style.display='block';
    } else {
       document.getElementById('xtraInfo').style.display='none';
    }  
}
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8fmDV/)

Answer (score 0):

The equal to conditional statement needs to have another equal sign. Also, you left a semi-colon off in the line that you defined the rejected variable

```
function checkValue() {
    var rejected = document.forms["frmcnt"]["ar"].checked;

    if(rejected == 'true') {
        document.getElementById('xtraInfo').style.display='';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('xtraInfo').style.display='none';
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be other problems with your code, but I did notice that you are doing

```
if (rejected = 'Rejected') {
```

instead of

```
if (rejected == 'Rejected') {
```

(two equal signs are required to check against a value)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function checkValue() {
        var rejected=document.forms["frmcnt"]["ar"].checked

        if (rejected = 'Rejected') {
            document.getElementById('xtraInfo').style.display='';
        } 
else if(rejected==false)
{
document.getElementById('TextContent').style.display='none';
}
else {
            document.getElementById('xtraInfo').style.display='none';
        }   
    }   
    </script>

    <textarea width="900" style="width: 910px; id="TextContent" resize:vertical;" name="rejectdt">
```